# How to draw ploygon in leaflet that use event?

Tags: leaflet, polygon

Is there only one way to draw a polygon through the [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin?

If you want draw anything, you must add the control ("map.addControl(drawControl);").

I want to draw a polygon on leaflet map by Event that I can trigger through any DOM event. Does anybody have a good idea how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want the user to draw a polygon?  Or you to do it ahead of time?  Or do it programmatically based on variables?

Comment: Some added details would be helpful, here.  Are you wanting to draw a circle of a particular size on-click?  Maybe a mocked-up picture would demonstrate what you are looking for.